# Insert white spaces between string with random numbers

Tags: sed

I want to insert a white space to every entry in a file that has same pattern with same letters but the numbers will be random

```
some text A01B02
some text A11B22
```

should become

```
some text A01 B02
some text A11 B22
```

Tried `sed` with wildcards but with no luck:

```
sed -i 's/A.*B.*/A.* B.*/g' file
sed -i 's/A*B*/A* B*/g' file
sed -i 's/A.B./A. B./g' file
sed -i 's/A[0-9]B[0-9]/A[0-9] B[0-9]/g' file
```

Comment: `sed -E 's/(...)(...)$/\1 \2/' file`?

Comment: Or `sed -E 's/^some text (...)(...)/some text\1 \2/' file`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look for the pattern `A - some digits - B - some digits - endofline`, use

```
sed -E 's/A([0-9]+)B([0-9]+)$/A\1 B\2/' file
```

Comment: Or alternatively: `sed -E 's/(A[0-9]+)(B[0-9]+)$/\1 \2/' file`